# Career change at 37: Should I start an Electronic Engineering MSc?

Tags: career-path, electrical-engineering

I have a BS in Electrical Engineering (2010) and a MSc in Computer Science. I completed the MSc with distinction at a British university in 2011 and have worked here in various IT roles since.

Now, at the age of 36, I would like to change careers and would like to work as an electronic engineer. I'm confident I can excel in the new career. Would a good 1 year MSc in Electronic Engineering here at a good UK university help me find a job? If I start the master's it would have to be in Autumn 2021 and by then, I will already be 37.

Comment: Ignore the age issue. Life is short. Make it sweet.

Comment: Are you interested in a career in academia? If not, then this question is probably better suited to workplace SE.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't know the UK job market, I'm from Germany.

I'd just apply for jobs that seem interesting to you, using your current degrees.

You got a solid background in EE from your BS, and your MSc shows that you have a broader knowledge and a somewhat interdisciplinary, scientific thinking, documented by the ability to switch from EE to CS. That should count as an asset.

What you don't have, is experience in electronics engineering, at least as far as we can tell from your question. But a year at university also doesn't give you that. So, you should find a way to convince the companies that you're capable of doing electronics designs at professional level.

My impression from the German job market is that companies desperately seek employees for hardware development, so they'll happily give people a try who are willing to do it.

Spending a year (or more) at university might be a fun time for you, but I don't think that necessary for applying to an engineering job. It might even be considered a weird decision by potential employers.

P.S. I myself have an EE diploma and a PhD in engineering and have always been working in IT, often in projects where EE knowledge was very welcome. A similar thing might work for you, just the other way round.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really appreciate it.